# How can I separate div from another class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In my WordPress based website a plugin automatically wraps every element in the post content with `<ul></ul>`. That wraps everything even the `<div>`s which is invalid.

I want to unwrap certain elements and tried jQuery `.unwrap` . But I am able to unwrap some elements  except a few div elements.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="post-content">
  <p>Example post content</p>
  <ul class="plugin_class">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>

    <ul>
      <div class="button-main-wrap">
        <span class="button-abc">
                                <span>
                                        <a href="http://test.com">Website link</a>
                                </span>
        </span>
        <span class="button-abc"></span>
        <span class="button-abc"></span>
      </div>
    </ul>

    <ul>

      <div class="number">hundred</div>
      <div class="number">thosand</div>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>This content is okay</div>
    <div>This content is okay</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the above code, I want to separate `<div class="button-main-wrap">` from `<ul class="plugin_class">` or stop the `<ul class="plugin_class">` to wrap elements which doesn't belong to it.  ex: the div `<div class="button-main-wrap">` or other elements like `<div class="number">`.

I tried these:

```js
jQuery("ul").find('.button-main-wrap').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-content">
  <p>Example post content</p>
  <ul class="plugin_class">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>

    <ul>
      <div class="button-main-wrap">
        <span class="button-abc">
                                <span>
                                        <a href="http://test.com">Website link</a>
                                </span>
        </span>
        <span class="button-abc"></span>
        <span class="button-abc"></span>
      </div>
    </ul>

    <ul>

      <div class="number">hundred</div>
      <div class="number">thosand</div>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>This content is okay</div>
    <div>This content is okay</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This unwraps all the `<ul>` elements in `.post-content` which I don't want.

```js
jQuery(".plugin_class").find('.button-main-wrap').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-content">
  <p>Example post content</p>
  <ul class="plugin_class">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>

    <ul>
      <div class="button-main-wrap">
        <span class="button-abc">
                                <span>
                                        <a href="http://test.com">Website link</a>
                                </span>
        </span>
        <span class="button-abc"></span>
        <span class="button-abc"></span>
      </div>
    </ul>

    <ul>

      <div class="number">hundred</div>
      <div class="number">thosand</div>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>This content is okay</div>
    <div>This content is okay</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't do anything.

I put all the code together in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/cLnXc/).

How to separate the `div` and stop the  to wrap elements un-necessarily?

Comment: There shouldn't be `div`s or `ul`s that are direct descendants of `ul`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html Whether you unwrap or not, either way the HTML will be invalid. That plugin is bad.

Comment: You are correct! But that's  what the plugin do.

Comment: I would be tempted to fix the plugin, you have an answer below though.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `div` is not a valid child of `ul`, so wrap the contents of the `ul` with `li` then unwrap the `li` elements so that the parent `ul` will get removed

```
$('.plugin_class > ul').each(function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<li />').contents().unwrap()
})
```

Demo: [Before](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7b8Qm/1/), [After](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7b8Qm/)

Comment: @arun-p-johny, I want to separate   `<div class="button-main-wrap"> </div>` and take it out from `<ul class="plugin_class"></ul>` entirely. So it looks like the same as `<div>This content is okay</div>`.

Comment: @Popnoodles I have modified the code hoping to achieve what I expected. But stuck somewhere.Here is my updated fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/7b8Qm/3/ . Hope you help!

Comment: @IamSJ what is the expected html

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your help! Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/t5J83/)**  with expected html. Only the `<li>` elements(WordPress custom fields) belongs to the plugin(`"plugin_class"`). 
1)I want to stop `"plugin_class"` to wrap other divs into it which are not it's own.2) the existing divs which don't belong to `"plugin_class"` and the content which were already wrapped un-necessarily by `"plugin_class"`  should be taken out.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I will try it. My jquery is in noconflict mode. Can you tell me how to use  $plugin(replacing $ with jQuery)?

Comment: @IamSJ sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tried this with no success- `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var jQuery(plugin) = jQuery('.plugin_class');
jQuery(plugin).find('> ul').remove().children().insertAfter(jquery(plugin))
});`

Comment: @IamSJ can you try to recreate the issue in the fiddle